# Calculation of areaUnderROC of logistic regression model in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, classification, logistic-regression, auc

I have a logistic regression model in Spark.
 I want to extract the probability for label=1 from the output vector and calculate the areaUnderROC.

```
val assembler = new VectorAssembler()
.setInputCols(Array("A","B","C","D","E"))--for example
.setOutputCol("features")

val data = assembler.transform(logregdata)

val Array(training,test) = data.randomSplit(Array(0.7,0.3),seed=12345)
val training1 = training.select("label", "features")
val test1 = test.select("label", "features")

val lr = new LogisticRegression()
val model = lr.fit(training1)
val results = model.transform(test1)
results.show()

label|            features|       rawPrediction|    probability|  prediction|
+-----+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+----------

  0.0|(54,[13,31,34,35,...|[2.44227333947447...|[0.91999457581425...|       0.0|

import org.apache.spark.mllib.evaluation.MulticlassMetrics

val predictionAndLabels =results.select($"probability",$"label").as[(Double,Double)].rdd
val metrics = new MulticlassMetrics(predictionAndLabels)
val auROC= metrics.areaUnderROC()
```

The probability looks like that:    [0.9199945758142595,0.0800054241857405]
How can I extract the probability for label=1 from the vector and calculate the AUC?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Isn't that what areaUnderROC would calculate by default?

Comment: It suppose to be. In Python the same model returns AUC=91%, in Spark AUC= 73%. I want to test it manually. How can i extract the probability value from the vector?

Answer (score 1):

You could get the value from the underlying `RDD`. This would return a `tuple` with your original label and the predicted value for `P(label=1)`:

```
val predictions = results.map(row => (row.getAs[Double]("label"), row.getAs[Vector]("probability")(0)))
```

Comment: I tried it and it's not working... I'm getting this warning:    
        org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Can't extract value from probability#5477;

Comment: Thanks. Seems that it worked.   predictions: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[(Double, Double)] = [_1: double, _2: double]
             But i can't show the results. I'm getting this error:  org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.DenseVector cannot be cast to org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector.  How can i see the predictions i received?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error, but you could try to specify the exact type: `import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.DenseVector`, then `val predictions = results.map(row => (row.getAs[Double]("label"), row.getAs[DenseVector]("probability")(0)))`

Comment: @ jamborta.please,I try your answer but I have this error java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Double .

Comment: try this: `val predictions = results.map(row => (row.getAs[Int]("label"), row.getAs[Vector]("probability")(0)))`

Comment: thanks alot . It worked but giving me all values of the probability .I want only for label=1.

Comment: you can add a filter `val predictions = results.filter(row => row.getAs[Int]("label") == 1).map(row => (row.getAs[Int]("label"), row.getAs[Vector]("probability")(0)))`